# Restore MySQL Database in Gitlab CI runner

Tags: mysql, continuous-integration, gitlab

This seems to be a fairly simple issue, but I am not able to get it working.

I need my MySQL DB to be loaded for running my E2E tests. Here is what I tried

Trial 1:

```
image: openjdk:8

services:
  - mysql:latest
...
...
...
e2e_tests:
  before_script:
    # install chrome
    - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable xvfb
    - rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    - apt-get --assume-yes install mysql-client
```

Chrome installation is going through fine, but for MySQL it says: **E: Unable to locate package mysql-client**

Trial 2:

```
image: openjdk:8

services:
  - mysql:latest
...
...
...
e2e_tests:
  before_script:
    # install chrome
    - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub  | apt-key add -
    - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable xvfb
    - rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    - cat "./DB/mysqlDumpFile.sql  | docker exec -i mysql /usr/bin/mysql -u $DB_USERNAME --password=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE"
```

It says: **Docker command not found**

I am sure it may work if I change my base image. But changing the base image to just load MySQL seems a bit overstretched. Is there any simple way to get this to work.

**Solution 1:**

```
image: openjdk:8

services:
  - mysql:latest
...
...
...
e2e_tests:
  before_script:
    # install chrome
    - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable xvfb
   # install mysql
    - wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.8-1_all.deb
    - dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.8-1_all.deb
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mysql-client
```

Comment: Apparently your image does not have an existing `/etc/apt/sources.list` entry from where it would be able to find mysql-client

Comment: I added Solution 1 to show what worked.  I'm sure there's a much cleaner solution, though.

Comment: Your solution is fine, the other way to do it would be to build a custom image based on openjdk that has Google Chrome xvfb and mysql client pre-installed which would reduce the amount of time it takes to run your tests, but forces you to do what you didn't want initially - changing your image

Comment: Yes, in hindsight your (@CliveMakamara) solution seems to be the most appropriate. My first instinct was to get it up and running and now that I have seen it run reasonably well [albeit slowly :-)], I will work on making a custom image as per your suggestion. Just curious, are there any limitations of using Custom Images - something like you need to be on a paid subscription model, etc.,?

Comment: No as long as you're image is either in the gitlab registry or any other public registry it's fine